# How many ip addresses do I need for a modem with 2 rj45 connections and does an isp assign them

Tags: networking, router

I have a modem that has 2 rj45 connections on it.
If I want to connect one rj45 cable to my router and the other one to a laptop how many ip address do I need and if I need 2 does my isp have to assign any iP address and is that 1 or 2 they have to assign

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What model modem? Have you looked at the manual?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you only need one publicly-routable IPv4 address, which goes to the WAN port of your router, and then your router does NAT to allow the traffic from any number of other devices on your network to appear to come from that one public address.